# Error while using async.parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, async.js

I am getting binding error while using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) in node.js. The code in question:

```
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function ignoreWhiteSpaceJudge(outDesired, outGenerated){

var contentOutDesired = "";
var contentOutGenerated = "";

async.parallel([

    function(outDesired, callback) {
           console.log(outDesired);

          fs.readFile(outDesired, 'utf8',function(error, data) {
                 if (error) {            
                      return callback(error);
                 } else {
                       contentOutDesired = data;
                      return callback();
                 }       
          });
    },

    function(outGenerated, callback) {

          fs.readFile(outGenerated, 'utf8', function(error, data) {
                 if (error) {            
                      return callback(error);
                 } else {
                       ontentOutGenerated = data;
                       return callback();
                 }       
          });
    }],

    function(error){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        else{
            console.log(contentOutDesired);
            console.log(ontentOutGenerated);
        }

    });
 }


var pathToOutDesired = path.normalize('/home/repos/gabbar/testcases/outputs/output_1_1.out');
var pathToOutGenerated = path.normalize('/home/repos/gabbar/testcases/outputs/output_1_2.out');

ignoreWhiteSpaceJudge(pathToOutDesired, pathToOutGenerated);
```

The error I am getting looks like this:

```
 [Function]

 fs.js:423
    binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
            ^
 TypeError: path must be a string
       at Object.fs.open (fs.js:423:11)
       at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:206:6)
       at async.parallel.fs.readFile.ontentOutGenerated          (/home/repos/gabbar/validation/ignoreWhiteSpaceJudge.js:17:18)
at /home/repos/gabbar/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:570:21
at /home/repos/gabbar/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:249:17
at /home/repos/gabbar/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:125:13
at Array.forEach (native)
at _each (/home/repos/gabbar/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:24)
at async.each (/home/repos/gabbar/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:124:9)
at _asyncMap (/home/repos/gabbar/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:13)
```

I am relatively new to node.js and trying to use `async` module for the first time. Could somebody help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your paths with the callback function of `parallel`.

Just remove the first parameter from your functions which is the callback and not your data:

```
function(callback) {
       console.log(outDesired);

      fs.readFile(outDesired, 'utf8',function(error, data) {
             if (error) {            
                  return callback(error);
             } else {
                   contentOutDesired = data;
                  return callback();
             }       
      });
},

function(callback) {

      fs.readFile(outGenerated, 'utf8', function(error, data) {
             if (error) {            
                  return callback(error);
             } else {
                   ontentOutGenerated = data;
                   return callback();
             }       
      });
}
```